# Vue call API key on header

Tags: api, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

**My API KEY** = 2356yhtujkiw

I am using AXIOS on VUEJS as for get/post request.

API document says to add that API key as on  `header` of all requests.

I tried setting it as `axios.defaults.headers.common['header'] = '2356yhtujkiw';` but it did not work.

**What's the proper way to define API KEY on header ?**

Comment: What does this have to do with vuejs? This will depend on how you are calling the API.

Comment: What you mean by that? I just have to add API key on header section and I can't find header section on VUE.

Comment: Have you tried searching the `axios` documentation instead of VUE? `axios` is your HTTP client, not Vue

Comment: Modifying `axios.defaults.headers.common` is correct, but you need to read the API documentation more carefully and find the actual name of the header it expects. Setting the `header` header is probably not what you want.

Comment: @hmm you were correct. The headers section on API document was defined as S-Api-Key. I just replaced header to S-API-KEY on axios.get and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can get confusing when you're starting out, and certain terms, like `header` could mean different things depending on context.

There are several ways you can achieve axios calls in vue.

- There's the "easy" one, where you add stuff right into a component
- you can integrate it into vuex
- create a custom helper/wrapper function (to use in a component or vuex)
- use a the vue axios plugin

On top of that there's more than one ways to implement axios

- reuse global instance
- create new instance for every call

without seeing your code it's hard to know which way you're using it, but I'm going to try to give steps for a way that should make it easy enough to replicate

create a `api.js` in your src folder with:

```js
import axios from 'axios'
let TOKEN = null;

export default {
  setHeader(val){
    TOKEN = val;
  },
  fetchUsers: () => {
    const instance = axios.create({
      baseURL: 'https://api.example.com',
      headers: {
        header: TOKEN
      }
    });
    // or: instance.defaults.headers.common['header'] = TOKEN;

    return instance.get('/users')
      .then((result) => {
        this.users = result.data
      })
  }
}
```

In a component, or Vuex, you can then...

```js
import api from '../api.js'

// set header
api.setHeader('abc123')

// make api call
api.fetchUsers().then(r=> {console.log(r)});
```

This (though untested code) should work...
It's not the cleanest way of using it, but should be easy to implement in existing code.

### TL;DR;

The reason `axios.defaults.headers.common['header'] = '2356yhtujkiw';` doesn't work is *likely* because you've already created the instance, and are re-using it. Updating the default would only apply for subsequent instances created. The example above gets around that, by not using any defaults, and just inserting the headers in every new instance, which is created for every new call.